# Overwrite Wordpress Core Function require_wp_db()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am integreating wordpress in my current website. But I got a Error saying my DB_HOST,DB_NAME,DB_USER are already defined. And thats true because I am running a login/member script that is using the same Constants.

So I renamed the wordpress constants in wp-config.php to DB_HOST1, DB_NAME1 etc..
To make wordpress running with that new Constant I need to change the wp-includes/load.php function require_wp_db() to:

```
function require_wp_db() {
    global $wpdb;

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/wp-db.php' );
    if ( file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' ) )
        require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' );

    if ( isset( $wpdb ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER1, DB_PASSWORD1, DB_NAME1, DB_HOST1 );
}
```

But when wordpress updates the installation I am worried that this gets overwritten because its a wordpress core file.

I tried to hook or filter the function in, but the hooks getting executed after db connection.

Any suggestions how to solve the issue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Modifying core files is never good. But if you must, an ugly workaround would be to make the file immutable using the `chattr` command from a linux shell:

```
 chattr +i wp-includes/load.php
```

This will prevent the file from being updated on future updates.